# How to handle JSON data using POST method?

Tags: javascript, spring

I have the following JSON in my request which is sended by JavaScript:

[image]

As you can see this is: String - String. Here is my JS code:

```
function saveSchemaInDatabase(schemaName, diagramJson) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("schemaName", schemaName);
    data.append("diagramJson", diagramJson);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase", true);
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data)));
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = { "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase" })
public String saveSchemaInDatabase(@RequestBody Map<String, String> map) {
    return "redirect:/user";
}
```

but i am getting error 415:

[image]

**Can someone tell me how can i get that 2x params in my controller?**

I tried also using DTO.
My DTO:

```
public class DTOTest {
    private String schemaName;
    private String diagramJson;

    public String getSchemaName() {
        return schemaName;
    }

    public void setSchemaName(String schemaName) {
        this.schemaName = schemaName;
    }

    public String getDiagramJson() {
        return diagramJson;
    }

    public void setDiagramJson(String diagramJson) {
        this.diagramJson = diagramJson;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = { "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase" })
public String saveSchemaInDatabase(@RequestBody DTOTest dtoTest) {
    return "redirect:/user";
}
```

the same error:
[image]

Comment: post your json in proper format. Also, mention what do you want to achieve/use-cases so that others can help you more conveniently. Btw, is your json format fixed or may vary per request ?

Comment: My Json format is always the same, String - String. I only want that 2x parameters "schemaName" "diagramJson" be handled by that controller.

Comment: if your json format is always same, then use @RequestBody annotation with a dto(containing field nameof your json) . It would be easier for us if your post your same json data, your controller class

Comment: I tried using DTO, check my post i just edited it. I am getting the same error. The problem is with that "content type" i am not sure why.

Comment: please check my answer if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your problem or not as there are some things vague to me. You can try this way:

1. Annotate your controller with @RestController
2. In your ajax sending json data, add `contentTyp` as `json` i.e:
     `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

And replace your tried code with this

```
@PostMapping(value =  "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase")
        public String saveSchemaInDatabase(@RequestBody DTOTest dtoTest) {
            return "redirect:/user";
        }
```

And please add your sample json data , not from browser console
P.S: your `diagramJson`  seems to be another json. you want that as string??

Comment: I want that diagramJson as Json i will parse him from java side

Comment: got it. Add. you can do it declaring another class as type to your outer class and catch that json string to your dto. It would save time to parse separately.

Comment: hmm sounds great but that json is "dynamic in some mean" and it is really really huge. So i would need a lot of time to create proper dto.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to send a `Content-Type` header with the value set to `text/json` in your JavaScript request.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
function saveSchemaInDatabase(schemaName, diagramJson) {
    ...
    xhttp.open("POST", "/user/saveSchemaInDatabase", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data)));
}
```